# Disable touch events for ScrollView inside ViewPager in Android

Tags: android, touch, android-viewpager, scrollview

I have ScrollViews as pages for ViewPager. I would like to disable touch events for that ViewPager completely. When I override onTouchEvent on my ViewPager class I only manage to prevent the horizontal scrolling but not the scrolling of the child ScrollViews.

How can I disable touch events entirely for ViewPager and all ScrollViews within it?

This is only a proof of concept for me. The next step is to prevent scrolling only for some part of that ViewPager.

Answer (score 1):

Overwrite the onInterceptTouchEvent of your scrollview to either consume or ignore the event:

"Return true to steal motion events from the children and have them dispatched to this ViewGroup through onTouchEvent(). The current target will receive an ACTION_CANCEL event, and no further messages will be delivered here."

```
public class InterceptScrollView extends ScrollView {

public InterceptScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    return false;
}

}
```

Comment: Why can't I intercept touch event on parent class (ViewPager in my case)?

Comment: I might be mistaken on this, but reading the documentation it seems to me that first the child receives the gestures and then that child decides either to or not to pass on the event to the parent.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#onInterceptTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent)